# Alternate access mapping for Azure internet-published SharePoint site, remains redundant redirect to *.cloudapp.net

Tags: azure, sharepoint, alternate-access-mappings

*I asked on sharepoint.stackexchange, but maybe this question is applicable to other websites too, so I ask here too.*

Hi! I have SharePoint portal in Azure, that I try to connect to my custom domain address.

I created and assigned static VIP to machine. 
Extended my Sharepoint application to internet zone, example mysite.cloudapp.net, set up it to use FBA authentication. Azure gives public name to machine so I accessed my site from internet via this address(by example "http://MySP.cloudapp.net"). All works.

Now I bought domain, created CNAME and A records few days ago, and added this address to Alternate Access Mappings in my SharePoint. By example it will be "http://MySP.com"

So alternate access mappings now are like this:

[image]

- first - is CA with port number
- next - internal address(Default)
- then Internet external address http://MySP.cloudapp.net
- next http://MySP.com that links to http://MySP.cloudapp.net

It works. But now if I type http://MySP.com, it changes in my browser to http://MySP.cloudapp.net. I don't want this, I want user to see only http://MySP.com(or http://www.MySP.com) header.

So I made backup and decided to delete http://MySP.cloudapp.net from AAM. After this if I type http://MySP.com I see in fiddler that there begins a loop and site does not open. I added it back but anyway got this loop. So now I restored and don't know - **how to set up http://MySP.com address for this Azure SharePoint portal correctly**?

I read this article, but it does not explain how to create two external addresses with no redirects
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx

**upd.:** in addition I can say that I also added http://**www**.mysite.com in Alternate Access Mappings, and it also changes in browser url field to http://mysite.**cloudapp.net**

Comment: Hm.. I think If someone clicks "minus" - it is normal to explain the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Recreated web app and retuned FBA settings in web.config:
"Update a web application URL and IIS bindings for SharePoint 2013"
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262366(v=office.15).aspx

Not the way that I would call a "silver bullet", but this helped.